# Which constructed language is most actively being developed?

Tags: statistics

[*This question*](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/140/which-constructed-language-has-the-largest-body-of-literature) shows Esperanto to likely be the largest conlang at the moment, but does not really indicate if the body of literature, number of speakers etc. is actually growing or stale. Are there any statistics to show the relative growth and popularity of different constructed languages?

I thought [Wikipedia](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias) could be useful and found [some ways](https://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/Sitemap.htm) to access raw data there, but that is probably not very representative.

Edit: To clarify, I would think growth could be defined as:

1. Expanding body of literature
2. Increasing number of speakers

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "most actively developed"? What do you mean by "growth" or "popularity"?

Comment: How about the one I just created?   Its lexicon has been continually expanding at a rate of 100% every minute

Comment: @Darkgamma Edited to clarify. Hope that helps

Comment: I think this is too broad unless you restrict it somehow.  The great majority of conlangs are not published--for example, I have a couple that nobody else has ever seen whose body of literature may be expanding.  If I teach my sister my new secret language, the body of speakers doubles in just a day.

Comment: @CHEESE Growth does not need to be a percentage. If you start at 1 and add 1, you grow at 100%. If you start at 10 and add 2, you grow at 20%, but 2 is still more "growth" than 1

Comment: @neelsg If a language with 1000 speakers gains 50, it has more growth than if a language with 2000 adds 50.  You said yourself that it wasn't based on size in your first sentence.

Comment: @CHEESE I would only be interested in body of literature that is public. As I explained earlier, if you teach your sister a new language, the number of speakers may have doubled, but it also only increased by one, so not really significant

Comment: The problem with this type of question is **it does not contain a specific problem statement** — what "problem" you are trying to solve specifically? The question appears ambiguous (or too broad) because users can only guess how to help you specifically. An overly broad premise becomes either a prelude to an ongoing discussion (not supported by this platform) or users start answering randomly so you can pick through the answers later (not how this site is supposed to work). Either way, this question is not currently *answerable* in  the context of this type of Q&A.