# What is the oldest known constructed language?

Tags: history

Historically speaking, what is the oldest known constructed language that we are able to determine with historical evidence?

Comment: That really depends on how you define conlang (see [this](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/109/100) answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The oldest language whose creator set out to actually invent a language (as opposed to Pāṇini, who wanted to create a classical standard out of an already  extant language) was probably [Lingua Ignota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_Ignota). The formerly brilliant Langmaker website had [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20051110160747/http://www.langmaker.com/db/mdl_linguaignota.htm) on it (now accessible through the Wayback Machine). It was made in the twelfth century, predating another early conlang, [Balaibalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaibalan), which was made somewhen between the fourteenth and sixteenth centuries.